# How to Customize Text Above Order Summary in Paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to Customize Text Above Order Summary in Paypal

Like the title says, I'd like to ask how to change the text above the order summary in Paypal. Right now it displays my email address, and I'd like to change it to something more formal, like "My Store" or something. I'm using http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/ to create my button, and here's the code that I got:

```
<script async="async"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=<email>"
    data-button="buynow"
    data-size="large"
    data-name="test name"
    data-quantity="1"
    data-amount="5"
    data-currency="USD"
    data-callback="<url>"
    data-return="<url>"
    data-env="sandbox"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: anyone got an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIthout being certain what text on what page you are referring to when you say "the text above the order summary" I may have the answer to your question:

First, if you want to always use a business name you should probably switch ("upgrade") to a business account. The difference between a PayPal personal/professional account and a PayPal Business account is that the former is presumed to be held by a person, and normally identified by the person's name or email.  The latter is presumed to be owned by a business, and is generally identified by the business name set in the account's payment settings profile pages.

Second, there is a BRANDNAME parameter that can be set to override the business name that will be displayed on the PayPal login and confirm-your-payment pages on a per-transaction basis in the classic APIs:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/